# Animating multiple UIViews simultaneously

Tags: ios, animation, uiview

I have three `UIButton` objects visually stacked one on top of another. When a user taps on a button the buttons below should move down a certain distance. I am using the following animation block:

```
// Assuming button 1 was clicked...
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25f
                      delay:0.0f
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                 animations:^(void) {
                   self.button2.frame = CGRectOffset(self.button2.frame, 0.0f, 20.0f);
                   self.button3.frame = CGRectOffset(self.button3.frame, 0.0f, 20.0f);
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) { NSLog(@"Finished"); }];
```

If I increase the animation duration, e.g. from `0.25` to `0.75`, the buttons do not remain together but they begin to move in different time intervals. I have tried with Core Animation methods, by grouping animations and other stuff, but haven't found any solution yet.

Do you have any ideas? Right now I'm keeping the duration in `0.25` until I come up with something.

Comment: Just as a note, at 0.25 they are more than likely also moving at different rates just not noticeable because of the speed. The most concrete solution to get animations linked is to use @bobnoble's solution. UIView animations are by default only animating an image of the original so it would ensure they stay together.

Comment: @RyanPoolos Of course, you're right. Not noticing that effect is sufficient until I find a better solution:)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One solution is to set both button2 and button3 as a subview in another `UIView` and animate the view instead of each of the buttons separately.  Whether this is a good approach depends on what you are trying to accomplish with the stacked button.

EDIT:

Since my experience is that animations within a block are in sync, I implemented the code as show below.  I tried numerous values for the animation duration (0.15, 0.25, 0.75, 1.25) and button2 and button3 are moving in sync (and since button2 is on top of button3, I can't actually see button3 at all, until I tap on button2, which causes button3 to move from underneath button 3).

```
- (IBAction)button1Tapped:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"button1Tapped...");

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.75f
                          delay:0.0f
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                     animations:^(void) {
                         self.button2.frame = CGRectOffset(self.button2.frame, 0.0f, 20.0f);
                         self.button3.frame = CGRectOffset(self.button3.frame, 0.0f, 20.0f);
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) { NSLog(@"Finished"); }];
}

- (IBAction)button2Tapped:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"button2Tapped...");

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.75f
                          delay:0.0f
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                     animations:^(void) {
                         self.button3.frame = CGRectOffset(self.button3.frame, 0.0f, 20.0f);
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) { NSLog(@"Finished"); }];
}

- (IBAction)button3Tapped:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"button3Tapped...");
}
```

Comment: I've thought of that, but if the number of buttons increases tomorrow this solution is not "scalable".

Comment: @elitalon why not?  Your buttons are already subviews of a view, it's just a matter of grouping them into another view.  I don't see why you should have trouble scaling this.  In fact it seems more scalable as your animation code will only need to animate one view.  Unless I misunderstood your requirements..

Comment: @Nebs Note that if I have 5 buttons I'd have to group 2, 3, 4 and 5 into a subview. But if I tap in button 2 I'd have to group 3, 4 and 5 in another subview. It's kind of a recursive grouping...

Comment: @elitalon - is there anything "special" about the `UIButton`s you are using?  Are they custom buttons with images, etc., or ???

Comment: @bobnoble Yep, they have a `UIImageView` added as a subview with a custom icon

Comment: @bobnoble Thanks for your effort! It seems that the solution involves using the option `UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut`. Or more specifically not using `UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear`, which was the first I tried. Now I see all buttons moving as they should.